# Macro not return list in Jinja2?

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2

In my Jinja2 code, Macro `getLisCustomer()` is used to get a returned list of customer ID and is defined as below:

```
{% macro getLisCustomer() %}
    {% set myList = [] %}
    {% if myList.append('CU001') %}{% endif %}
    {% if myList.append('CU002') %}{% endif %}
    {% if myList.append('CU003') %}{% endif %}
{{myList}}
{% endmacro %}
```

However, when I tried to get an individual customer ID from macro `getLisCustomer()`, I get a list of single character instead of individual customer ID in a list.

```
{% set TotalList = getLisCustomer() %}
{% for row in TotalList %}
    <p>{{row}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The result is something like this `[ ' C U 0 0....`.

What's wrong? How can I get list element from macro `getLisCustomer()` in Jinja2?

**Added**: I just realized that the root cause might be that my macro does not return a list but a list-like string, that is why in `for-loop` return every single character instead of list element. Therefore, how could we convert a list-like string into an actual list?

Comment: Expression `{{...}}` evaluates to a **string representation** of whatever inside a double braces. I cannot imaging a macro which returns non-string.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, you are right, I tried an alternative to convert my string into a list by having this ```[getLisCustomer()]```, yet the whole list element is become only one list element. Can be any possible to get it as a normal list element, this case, 3 list elements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as simple as a comma-separated list representation which you split into a list when consuming:

```
{% macro getLisCustomer() -%}
    {% set myList = [] -%}
    {% if myList.append('CU001') %}{% endif -%}
    {% if myList.append('CU002') %}{% endif -%}
    {% if myList.append('CU003') %}{% endif -%}
{% for i in myList %}{{ i }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor -%}
{% endmacro %}
```

<sup>This could be further simplified, because you don't really need to create `myList`, you can print the values immediately.</sup>

Then:

```
{% set TotalList = getLisCustomer().split(',') -%}
{% for row in TotalList %}
    <p>{{row}}</p>
{%- endfor %}
```

---

<sup>Or if for some reason you wanted to implement a data exchange protocol you could create custom filters in Python (see my [first edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52121736/1) based on how Ansible extends Jinja2).</sup>

Answer (score -1):

2023 answer:

```
{{ return(myList) }}
```

Comment: When was this supposedly added? I found [a possible reference to this on an obscure website](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/return) but it doesn't seem to work with my Jinja2 installation.